# Converting MBCS stream to UTF-8 and vice versa in C++

Tags: c++, encoding, utf-8, mbcs

I'm using Visual C++ (VS2005) and compiling the project in Multibyte Character Set (MBCS). However, the program needs to communicate with a webapp (which is in utf-8) via XMLRPC. So I'm thinking maybe I can use MBCS internally and convert the strings to utf-8 before sending them to the xmlrpc module and converting them back to MBCS after receiving from the webapi.

I'm wondering what's the best way to convert between MBCS and UTF-8 in VC++?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

Call [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms776413(VS.85).aspx) to convert your string to unicode followed by a call to [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms776420(VS.85).aspx) to convert the unicode to UTF-8. Reverse the process to go the other way,

Answer (score 2):

You could try [wcstombs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d7tc9zw(VS.80).aspx) / [mbstowcs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1f9b8cy(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use CT2A and pass CP_UTF8 as the code page, e.g.:

```
CT2A pszUTF8(_T("My DBCS string"), CP_UTF8);
// pszUTF8.m_psz contains the UTF8 string.
```

To go back again:

```
CA2T pszT(_T("My UTF8 string"), CP_UTF8);
// pszT.m_psz contains the TCHAR string.
```